# Does Crashlytics handle EXC_RESOURCE when it makes the app crash (e.g. CPU_FATAL)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

We received some crash reports from our users like this one:

```
Event:            cpu usafe
Action taken:     Process killed
CPU:              9 seconds cpu time over 13 seconds (69% cpu average), exceeding limit..
```

But we were not able to find the matching reports in the Fabric/Crashlytics web interface. Some mach exceptions are "silent" (eg. EXC_RESOURCE - WAKEUPS), but some other will make the app terminate (EXC_RESOURCE - CPU_FATAL).

Does Crashlytics handle those fatal exceptions? Are we suppose to see them in the Crashlytics interface?

Comment: Not certain it would help you find the issue anyway.  These quota-like exceptions are almost certainly not triggered where you can find the reason.  The general reason is using too much CPU so you need to profile your project to figure out where that happens.

Comment: You're right, but before spending a lot of time in optimizing the app's CPU usage, I would like to be able to monitor this problem (how many users are impacted).

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

This looks like an out of memory error, which Crashlytics cannot handle as a normal crash report. If the OS decides to reclaim some memory and kill your app process, Crashlytics can't use the same mechanisms to capture that fatal error the same way we capture conventional errors, and instead has to use best-effort heuristics to infer that an OOM occurred.

More helpful information on that and how to fix OOMs here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/OOMs.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, first line of your link: `Crashlytics reports crashes caused by signals, Mach exceptions and uncaught C++/Obj-C exceptions`.
Don't think OOMs (memory / RAM) incidents are related to Mach exceptions (like EXC_RESOURCE, the one I was asking for some more info).